# travis encrypt-file for maven deploy

Tags: travis-ci, gnupg

**On my computer:**

```
travis login --org
Username: xxxxxx
Password: xxxxxx
Successfully logged in as xxxxxx!
travis encrypt-file codesigning.asc -r XXXXXX/XXXXXX
encrypting codesigning.asc for XXXXXX/XXXXXX
storing result as codesigning.asc.enc
storing secure env variables for decryption

Please add the following to your build script (before_install stage in your .travis.yml, for instance):

    openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_abcd1234_key -iv $encrypted_abcd1234_iv -in codesigning.asc.enc -out codesigning.asc -d

Pro Tip: You can add it automatically by running with --add.

Make sure to add codesigning.asc.enc to the git repository.
Make sure not to add codesigning.asc to the git repository.
Commit all changes to your .travis.yml.
```

**On my travis acount:**

[image]

**On my GitHub repository:**

I paste the `codesigning.asc.enc` file in the `test` folder `test/codesigning.asc.enc`.

I add this shell script:

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = 'master' ] && [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == 'false' ]; then
     echo "******** Starting gpg"
     openssl aes-256-cbc -K "$encrypted_abcd1234_key" -iv "$encrypted_abcd1234_iv" -in test/codesigning.asc.enc -out test/codesigning.asc -d
     gpg --fast-import test/codesigning.asc
fi
```

**I have this error on my travis console:**

```
bad decrypt
139864985556640:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
gpg: invalid radix64 character FE skipped
gpg: invalid radix64 character C4 skipped
gpg: read_block: read error: invalid packet
gpg: import from `test/codesigning.asc' failed: invalid keyring
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenPGP (the cryptographic protocol implemented by `gpg`) and X.509 (the cryptographic protocol used by OpenSSL) are not compatible. You cannot import this key to GnuPG (you could to `gpgsm` which implements X.509, but this is not the normal `gpg` you want to use). You will have to stick with OpenSSL or GnuTLS to handle the key and encrypted messages for it.

Comment: Note: Git 2.19 will support x509 certs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919818/6309